# Need to add one more column 'LastName' for filter. if available in datasource in below code. angular data table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
private performFilter(filterBy: string) {    
filterBy = filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase();
    --- returning value
        return this.dataSource.filter(
          (data: any) =>
           data.FirstName ? data.FirstName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1 : ""
        );
 }
```

Comment: Please extend your question and format your code. I've no idea what you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I understand that you want to do is to filter some array depending on underneath values like in the below example :

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=38&pc=1#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-uD4djkfQRoLR6zpbzrCLZaraNbZyuDxeE7loA)

```
class Foo {
    public dataSource: {
        FirstName: string;
        LastName: string;
    }[] = [{
        FirstName: 'Obiwan',
        LastName: 'Kenobi',
        }, {
         FirstName: 'Bob',
        LastName: 'Franklin',
    }, {
         FirstName: 'Anakin',
        LastName: 'skywalker',
    }];

    public performFilter(filterBy: string) {
        const toFilterBy = filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase();

        return this.dataSource.filter((data) => {
            // Check for FirstName
            if (data.FirstName && data.FirstName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(toFilterBy) !== -1) {
                return true;
            }

            // Check for LastName
            if (data.LastName && data.LastName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(toFilterBy) !== -1) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        });
    }
}

const foo = new Foo();

console.log('------- Before', foo.dataSource);

console.log('------- After', foo.performFilter('Obiwan'));
```

---

---

Now that we can see a pattern that is repeating itself, we can generalize :

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=33&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOBlA9gVwE4GNoF4oDeAUFKVAGICWGAzsAHJwC2EAXFHRpQHYDmA3CTIAZOHUYt2nHgKIBfQUSwAbMTQooUhIaTBoARsspYoAEwTJ02NrAupMOANoBdKPkfEyXitXHMbAOQA8vqUAO5w3AEANDreon6SUAEA0hDcKKExcV5y0dreXlS0DP7sAQBCmdmFpAmlSQHkGJEA1kZRsbn5nrU+JRKBAILccK08NbX1g+U0rSARyq0QGJOkcs6KXnqGxlCQGABmKBhMVMrAKwAUh5QXKxUgUsBcfACUBbVYKNx0UMAoc6XDCPNxQW73EEgAB0AOEKCwcGUEHhYRWAGExBArm8trUMBBgJhuP8ABaUGjQ8yIezWaEQ4FXK7UuDseA0qw4D64AB8UCujhytSavgaEDWfWS038Eq8rjE-OWIBQh1sHIcEDeLje0JoKBYVwAHm4+SzHIbXAAyS1mCzm5ywlDwxHI1EYrE46E8UwQQ1BQ5XAFAh4gD4AQlw+AAtABGN64uJyeREJQ-P7HLT4bgQMIaFA4xTfX4oZHQ5QoXhXAJRmu1qNQCoQY4EmLgzRUuyczWFtMliBlitVuu1qBDQ7A1sZ6EHZtnO6M4KhCJReOCIA)

```
type DataSource = {
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
};

class Foo {
    public dataSource: DataSource[] = [{
        FirstName: 'Obiwan',
        LastName: 'Kenobi',
        }, {
         FirstName: 'Bob',
        LastName: 'Franklin',
    }, {
         FirstName: 'Anakin',
        LastName: 'skywalker',
    }];

    public performFilter(filterBy: string) {
        const toFilterBy = filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase();

        return this.dataSource.filter((data: DataSource) => ([
            'FirstName',
            'LastName',
        ] as (keyof DataSource)[]).some(x => data[x] && data[x].toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(toFilterBy) !== -1));
    }
}

const foo = new Foo();

console.log('------- Before', foo.dataSource);

console.log('------- After', foo.performFilter('Obiwan'));
```